# Как пройти по DOM и собрать данные с input в древовидный объект?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5, html-form

Как обойти input страницы и записать их значения в древовидный объект? Все блоки добавляются динамически, их количество не ограниченно.
html разметка:

```
<div id="form" class="form">
<div class="block1">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Дата" id="date">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Вид загрузки" id="carType">
  <div class="block2" id="1">
    <input type="text" class="out" placeholder="Исходящий" id="1">
    <div class="add4">4</div>
    <div class="block3" id="1">
      <input type="text" class="point" placeholder="Пункт" id="1">
      <div class="add3">3</div>
      <div class="block4" id="1">
        <input type="text" class="car" placeholder="ТС" id="1">
        <div class="add2">2</div>
        <div class="block5" id="1">
          <div class="add1">1</div>
          <input type="file" class="amount" id="1">

        <input type="file" class="amount" id="2"></div>
      </div>
    <div class="block4" id="2">
        <input type="text" class="car" placeholder="ТС" id="2">
        
        <div class="block5" id="1">
          <div class="add1">1</div>
          <input type="file" class="amount" id="1">

        <input type="file" class="amount" id="2"></div>
      </div></div>
  <div class="block3" id="2">
      <input type="text" class="point" placeholder="Пункт" id="2">
      
      <div class="block4" id="1">
        <input type="text" class="car" placeholder="ТС" id="1">
        <div class="add2">2</div>
        <div class="block5" id="1">
          <div class="add1">1</div>
          <input type="file" class="amount" id="1">

        <input type="file" class="amount" id="2"></div>
      </div>
    <div class="block4" id="2">
        <input type="text" class="car" placeholder="ТС" id="2">
        
        <div class="block5" id="1">
          <div class="add1">1</div>
          <input type="file" class="amount" id="1">

        <input type="file" class="amount" id="2"></div>
      </div></div></div>
<div class="block2" id="2">
    <input type="text" class="out" placeholder="Исходящий" id="2">
    
    <div class="block3" id="1">
      <input type="text" class="point" placeholder="Пункт" id="1">
      <div class="add3">3</div>
      <div class="block4" id="1">
        <input type="text" class="car" placeholder="ТС" id="1">
        <div class="add2">2</div>
        <div class="block5" id="1">
          <div class="add1">1</div>
          <input type="file" class="amount" id="1">

        <input type="file" class="amount" id="2"></div>
      </div>
    <div class="block4" id="2">
        <input type="text" class="car" placeholder="ТС" id="2">
        
        <div class="block5" id="1">
          <div class="add1">1</div>
          <input type="file" class="amount" id="1">

        <input type="file" class="amount" id="2"></div>
      </div></div>
  <div class="block3" id="2">
      <input type="text" class="point" placeholder="Пункт" id="2">
      
      <div class="block4" id="1">
        <input type="text" class="car" placeholder="ТС" id="1">
        <div class="add2">2</div>
        <div class="block5" id="1">
          <div class="add1">1</div>
          <input type="file" class="amount" id="1">

        <input type="file" class="amount" id="2"></div>
      </div>
    <div class="block4" id="2">
        <input type="text" class="car" placeholder="ТС" id="2">
        
        <div class="block5" id="1">
          <div class="add1">1</div>
          <input type="file" class="amount" id="1">

        <input type="file" class="amount" id="2"></div>
      </div></div></div></div>
<button class="sub-btn" id="btn">Отправить</button>
```

Пример заполненной формы:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как при помощи нативного JavaScript или при помощи jQuery (Или других библиотек) получить данные со всех полей с сохранением иерархии в древовидный объект?
Пример объекта которого я хочу получить:

```
var array = {
block1_1: {
    value: "1123",
    block2_1: {
        value: "1",
        block3_1: {
            value: "Т700АК",
            block5_1: {
                value: "1.mp4"
            },
            block5_2: {
                value: "2.mp4"
            }
        },
        block3_2: {
            value: "Т654АК",
            block5_1: {
                value: "3.mp4"
            },
            block5_2: {
                value: "4.mp4"
            }
        }
    },
    block2_2: {
        value: "2",
        block3_1: {
            value: "Т689АК",
            block5_1: {
                value: "5.mp4"
            },
            block5_2: {
                value: "6.mp4"
            }
        },
        block3_2: {
            value: "Т669АК",
            block5_1: {
                value: "7.mp4"
            },
            block5_2: {
                value: "8.mp4"
            }
        }
    },
},
block1_2: {
    value: "1124",
    point_1: {
        value: "1",
        block3_1: {
            value: "Т692АК",
            block5_1: {
                value: "9.mp4"
            },
            block5_2: {
                value: "10.mp4"
            }
        },
        block3_2: {
            value: "Е404ОН",
            block5_1: {
                value: "11.mp4"
            },
            block5_2: {
                value: "12.mp4"
            }
        }
    },
    point_2: {
        value: "2",
        block3_1: {
            value: "Н190МТ",
            block5_1: {
                value: "13.mp4"
            },
            block5_2: {
                value: "14.mp4"
            }
        },
        block3_2: {
            value: "О839МУ",
            block5_1: {
                value: "15.mp4"
            },
            block5_2: {
                value: "16.mp4"
            }
        }
    }
}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Если собираешься отправлять файлы через JSON, то скорее всего никак...

Если приёмщик PHP или NodeJS то можно вот так. Что в express body-parser, что PHP Умеют понимать вот такой вот синтаксис.

```
<?php

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    echo "<h1>Post Fields</h1>";
    echo "<pre><code>";
    print_r($_POST);
    echo "</code></pre>";

    echo "<h1>Post Files</h1>";
    echo "<pre><code>";
    print_r($_FILES);
    echo "</code></pre>";
}

?><form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>">
    <p>p1v</p>
    <input name="point[1][value]">
    <p>p1c1</p>
    <input name="point[1][car][1][value]">
    <p>p1c1f1</p>
    <input type="hidden" name="point[1][car][1][file][1]" value="point_1_car_1_file_1">
    <input name="point_1_car_1_file_1" type="file">
    <p>p1c1f2</p>
    <input type="hidden" name="point[1][car][1][file][2]" value="point_1_car_1_file_2">
    <input name="point_1_car_1_file_2" type="file">
    <p>p2v</p>
    <input name="point[2][value]">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

- https://riptutorial.com/php/example/27569/passing-arrays-by-post

На выходе получается следующий массив

```
Post Fields
Array
(
    [point] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [value] => p1v
                    [car] => Array
                        (
                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [value] => p1c1
                                    [file] => Array
                                        (
                                            [1] => point_1_car_1_file_1
                                            [2] => point_1_car_1_file_2
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [value] => p2v
                )

        )

)
Post Files
Array
(
    [point_1_car_1_file_1] => Array
        (
            [name] => 0000001.png
            [type] => image/png
            [tmp_name] => /tmp/php6D9F.tmp
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 766645
        )

    [point_1_car_1_file_2] => Array
        (
            [name] => 0000002.png
            [type] => image/png
            [tmp_name] => /tmp/php6DB0.tmp
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 803329
        )

)
```

Comment: Данные будут передаваться в python.